# Can't connect to my database (RDS) using mySQL and EF 5

Tags: mysql, wpf, amazon-web-services, entity-framework-5

I have the following problem:

I want to start my WPF application from an EC2 instance. This application should connect to a mySQL database located on an RDS instance.
Unfortunately I can't connect to the database.

The error message (inner exeption) that pops up is:

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.

**Using @ AWS:**

- MySQL 5.6.27  (RDS; AZ: eu-central-1a)
- Windows Server 2012 R (EC2, AZ: eu-central-1b, t2.micro)

**Using @ Application:**

- EF 5.0
- .NET Framwork 4.5.2

**On AWS site:**

- connection between EC2 and RDS works fine
- can connect to the database with mySQL Workbench (on server)
- direct connection to the database starting the WPF application on my local PC works fine

**Edit:**

I guess it might be an issue with the .NET Framework
I've already took a look into the machine.config in the tag "DBProviderFactories". Originally no special provider was given. I tried to add the mySQL Provider entry I have in my machine.config on my local  machine.
Now I got some other error message (not related to .NET Framework) and try to figure out why it is thrown.

Provider I entered:

`<add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />`

I really wonder what I can do here additionally? It is driving me nuts.
Did I forgot to instal something for .NET Framework or mySQL on the Server?

Thank you so much for your help!

**Edit 2:**
The problem could be solved by configure the  client application correctly (there was a missing reference to MySQL). It was done by a colleague.

Comment: I would suggest that this is a .Net error, rather than an AWS error, as in you don't have a supporting .Net library on the EC2 Instance. Do a Google for 'Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed' and see what you can find.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure that this might be a .NET error. I also do a search and tried solutions which where suggested such as look into the machine.config file etc. The correc .NET Framework is installed :(

Comment: Error was finally fixed. Something in the client application was not well configured. It was probably related to a missing reference to MySQL, which was needed because the client application did then run on the websever.